# StringFormat Binding with Apostrophe in XAML Not Working

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, data-binding, string-formatting

I'm working in Silverlight 4 and I'm trying to insert an apostrophe in a value that is bound to a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyValue, StringFormat='The value is &apos;{0}&apos;'}"/>
```

However, I'm getting XAML parse errors even though I have tried escaping with it with `\'` and `&quot;` to no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work in WPF or Silverlight.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="Format">The value is '{0}'</system:String>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyValue, StringFormat={StaticResource Format}}"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: For those who may stumble upon this because their `StringFormat` is not working in a Tab control's header; that is not a string control. One has to break out the header's content into a `TextBlock` and then use the `StringFormat`.