# How can I bind or otherwise get & set a value of a control in a resource?

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

How can I bind a control inside a usercontrol resource to a property? Alternatively, can I find the control from the code behind and get & set the value from there?

Here is my markup. I've stripped it down to just the relevant part:

> Salesmen.xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="EditAppointmentTemplate1" TargetType="local:SchedulerDialog" x:Name="ControlTemplate">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid Name="grdTotal" Grid.Row="4" Visibility="{Binding ResourceTypesVisibility}">
                            <TextBox x:Name="totalSalesmen" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Width="120" Text="{Binding Parent.totalSalesmen, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="EditAppointmentDialogStyle1" TargetType="local:SchedulerDialog">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource EditAppointmentTemplate1}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderBrush="Transparent">
            <telerik:RadCalendar Name="RadCalendar" SelectedDate="{Binding CurrentDate, ElementName=RadScheduleViewTests, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTodayHighlighted="True"
                         telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Metro" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday" Margin="0,0,15,0"
                         SelectionChanged="RadCalendar_SelectionChanged_1"  >
            </telerik:RadCalendar>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>

    <telerik:RadScheduleView Name="RadScheduleViewTests"  MinAppointmentWidth="100" Tag="{Binding Path=Context, ElementName=TestDayPage}"
                             telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Metro" Grid.Column="1" EditAppointmentDialogStyle="{StaticResource EditAppointmentDialogStyle1}"
                             AppointmentCreating="RadScheduleViewTests_AppointmentCreating_1" AppointmentEditing="RadScheduleViewTests_AppointmentEditing_1"
                             AppointmentDeleting="RadScheduleViewTests_AppointmentDeleting_1" FirstDayOfWeek="Sunday" ShowDialog="RadScheduleViewTests_ShowDialog_1"
                             AppointmentEdited="RadScheduleViewTests_AppointmentEdited_1">
        <telerik:RadScheduleView.DragDropBehavior>
            <examiners:CustomDragDropBehaviour/>
        </telerik:RadScheduleView.DragDropBehavior>
        <telerik:RadScheduleView.SchedulerDialogHostFactory>
            <test:CustomScheduleViewDialogHostFactory />
        </telerik:RadScheduleView.SchedulerDialogHostFactory>
        <telerik:RadScheduleView.ViewDefinitions>
            <telerik:DayViewDefinition/>
            <telerik:WeekViewDefinition/>
            <telerik:MonthViewDefinition/>
            <telerik:TimelineViewDefinition/>
        </telerik:RadScheduleView.ViewDefinitions>
    </telerik:RadScheduleView>
</Grid>
```

And here's my property. Despite the two-way binding it is always null:

> Salesmen.xaml.cs:

```
string totalSalesmen { get; set; }
```

I've heard about the [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) and the [LogicalTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.aspx). These might enable another approach - finding the control and getting and them manually. However, VisualTreeHelper only sees the LayoutRoot and it's children (not UserControl.Resources), and LogicalTreeHelper does not seem to be available (it's a SilverLight 5 project; I don't know what framework is used by Silverlight 5. I understand that LogicalTreeHelper is only available in 4.5 and later)

Thank you for you assistance. **Note: this question will get a +50 bounty**. The system requires me to wait for 2 days to put a bounty, so I will put the bounty and accept the answer after 2 days. I will let you know if your answer works before that.

Comment: Hi, the bounty will not be awarded if you do not assign it manually.

Comment: :((( Has the system changed? I thought it would get awarded automatically when the answer was selected. I got a message from the system saying 'Your bounty on question "How can I bind or otherwise get & set a value of a control in a resource?" is completed and will be auto-awarded in 24 hours.'. Please confirm if you have received it.

Comment: No, haven't received it. But I think you can still award bounty points to an answer you like, independent from the question-bounty system.

Comment: Ah, after reading the documentation, I think it awarded you only half the bounty, as it was automatically awarded. I don't like these "gotchas" with the bounty system - it really should be more straightforward. I was under the impression that selecting a correct answer would itself award the bounty (what possible reason could I have to mark one answer as the correct one and yet give a different one the bounty?

Comment: Anyway, I will award a bounty on another of your answers. I will award it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673509/cant-i-use-apostrophe-in-stringformat-of-xaml-binding-silverlight/26675176#26675176. I now know that I have to award it manually :)

Comment: It did not award half the bounty, it did award nothing. Auto-Bounty can only be awarded for answers that were created **after** the bounty was set.

Comment: Thanks for going through all the hassle to still assign a bounty, I sure owe you a beer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `Binding` to *totalSalesmen* and everything inside the *EditAppointmentTemplate1* will not have any effect as long as the `Template` is never instantiated.
Think of a `Template` (both ControlTemplate and DataTemplate) as a blueprint. The elements that are defined inside are only instantiated when the template is used somewhere.

Do you have a usage somewhere? like this:

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <SchedulerDialog Template="{StaticResource EditAppointmentTemplate1}"/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

**[Edit #1]**

Ok let's see... your twoway `Binding` to *totalSalesmen* looks ok, albeit a bit smelly. I think the property *totalSalesmen* should rather live in the `DataContext` (and it would be easier to bind against).
But first let's try to make your code work, maybe we make it nice later:

**The Problem**

When (in one single xaml file) using `ElementName` in `Bindings` while at the same time using templates to define parts of the UI (and remember: the stuff in templates is only created when it is used somewhere, and the creation may happen at a different point in time) there is the risk, that elements that you expect to know each other are in fact created in diffent [NameScopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189026%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). And your affected ElementName-Bindings won't work. Just silently won't work.

**A Cure**

You can try a trick: Ensure that you have a `StaticResource` that holds the reference to the element you originally wanted to use by `ElementName`.
And then you just write a `Binding` against that `StaticResource`. See what I've done here:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Salesmen" ... x:Name="me">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <BindableObjectReference x:Key="MyUserControl" Object="{Binding ElementName=me}"/>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="EditAppointmentTemplate1"
        TargetType="local:SchedulerDialog">
        ...
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Object.totalSalesmen,
            Source={StaticResource MyUserControl}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        ...
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>
```

and the code

```
public class BindableObjectReference : DependencyObject
{
    public object Object
    {
        get { return GetValue( ObjectProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ObjectProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Object", typeof( object ),
        typeof( BindableObjectReference ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );
}
```

**[Edit #2]**

When you bind to a property of the DataContext, you just specify the path but not the source (implicitly the source will be the DataContext):

```
Text="{Binding Path=totalSalesmen, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: +1. Sorry, I missed the schedulerDialog while posting, as I was trying to keep the code to a minimum. It still comes null. Is the binding expression {Binding Parent.totalSalesmen, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=TwoWay} correct?

Comment: Best thing would be to edit your question and show the relevant part. I have an idea what's wrong, but when I can't see the relevant parts its just speculation.

Comment: @Zesty: ? I can't see where and how you are using the template.

Comment: I've added the <Style x:Key="EditAppointmentDialogStyle1" TargetType="local:SchedulerDialog">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource EditAppointmentTemplate1}" />
    </Style> Is this what's required?

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, Martin. I'm not able to add <BindableObjectReference x:Key="MyUserControl" Object="{Binding ElementName=me}"/>, even though I've defined the class within the same namespace of the XAML page. Does it need to implement any interface, or do I have to add any XML namespace at the top of the page to get it to work?

Comment: On the other hand, I was able to add totalSalesmen as a property within the class that is the DataContext for the template (thanks to your post!). I've also verified that it is getting and setting properly to the EF. Unfortunately, I still can't get the binding to work. Is my syntax correct (assuming that I've added it to the DataContext): <TextBox x:Name="countSalesmen" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Width="120" Text="{Binding totalSalesmen, ElementName=ControlTemplate, Mode=TwoWay}" />

Comment: You have to add a xaml namespace when you use your own classes: <someLocalNamespace:BindableObjectReference .../> I use resharper and therefore not really think about the xaml namespaces because resharper will suggest the correct namespace and it's only one click for me with the mouse.

Comment: And regarding your second question: the Binding is wrong, when you bind to properties in the DataContext you do not use the ElementName but just set the path: Text="{Binding Path=totalSalesmen, Mode=TwoWay}"

Answer (score 1):

If you Add TotalSalesmen to the DataContext of the template, e.g.

```
public class SpecialAppointment: Appointment
{
  private int _totalSalesmen = 0;
  public int TotalSalesmen 
  {get {return _totalSalesmen; }
  {set {_totalSalesmen = value; OnPropertyChanged(()=> this.TotalSalesmen);}
}
```

You should be able to bind the text box thus:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TotalSalesmen, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

*Note* the binding is case-sensitive, and it must match the property name `TotalSalesmen` and not the field `_totalSalesmen`.